# file_copy() does not work

Tags: media

I have the following code.

```php
$main_image = glob('main*.{jpeg,gif,png,jpg,JPEG,JPG,PNG}', GLOB_BRACE);
if (count($main_image) != 1) {
  die("Could not find main picture !");  
    
  $file_path = drupal_realpath($main_image[0]);
  $file = (object) array(
    'uid' => $userID,
    'uri' => $file_path,
    'filemime' => file_get_mimetype($file_path),
    'display' => 1,
    'filename' => $main_image[0],
  );

  $destination = "public://galerii_imagini/" . $file->filename;

  if ($file = file_copy($file, $destination, FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE)) {}
  else {
    die("Could not copy " . $file_path . " in " . $destination);
  }
}
```

In the Drupal logs, the error message is the following.

> File ..../main_ROSE2106.JPG could not be copied, because the destination directory public://galerii_imagini is not configured correctly.

What should I do to configure it correctly?
In /admin/config/media/file-system I set the the path for public files (sites/default/files) and set the file permissions for that directory recursively to 777.

Comment: Function [`file_copy`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21file.inc/function/file_copy/7.x) and called by it function [`file_unmanaged_copy`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21file.inc/function/file_unmanaged_copy/7.x) in case of errors write messages to the system log. Did you look at the "Recent log messages" report? Most likely you will find answer there...

Comment: Check your files directory is writable or not. If not then give it to write permission.

Comment: How about the directory permission on `/sites/default/files/galerii_imagini` ?

Comment: 777 on both directory and files inside

Comment: Remember to do chmod -R 777  /sites/default/files. The -R makes it recursive for the subfolders

Comment: I am on shared hosting so I don't have access to root. I executed the command through Filezilla but the folder and the files inside have 777 rights.

Comment: @applecrusher This is very bad advice.

Comment: And what if you use real path instead of "public://..."?

Comment: Same error. Now it's showing me the full address and not the one with public:// 
I will move to a droplet from DO in about a month. If I have the same problem I will be back. Having access to the root might solve this problem.

Comment: Are you certain that sites/default/files/galerii_imagini exists and is a directory? You could see this error either if it doesn't exist or if it exists but is a file instead of a directory. If you expect Drupal to create the galerii_imagini directory, you need to call `file_prepare_directory("public://galerii_imagini", FILE_CREATE_DIRECTORY);` before `file_copy()`.

Comment: "galerii_imagini" exists and it's a directory. Is writable by drupal because I can create manual galleries that store the images in this directory. Because I am on a shared hosting and I had rights problem in the past I am not sure that what I am seeing in the filezilla is correct, regarding the rights.

Comment: Tell me more about the environment, do you migrate another server ? what is your OS and version? What is your Web server( apache or nginx lightspeed etc) ?